# MVC: should Model return error message or error code

Tags: php

I currently implementing a website, using PHP and my own MVC framework.

When user execute operation like add/edit I first validate input.
If something went wrong the model return a Result object, containing list error messages of what went wrong, to controller.

The controller, in case errors occur, forward the Result object messages to View for rendering

my question: Is it wise for the model to sends a list of **text message** describing the error, or instead it is better to return a list of **error codes**(int), and it will be the responsebility of the controller to parse them and convert them to text messages, before passing it to view?
Any help would be appreciated

**EDIT - Adding some code ----**

```
class Result{
    ...
    function addError($msg);
    function getErrors();           // return an array of messages
    function isSuccess();           // return bool. 
    ...
}

class MyModel extends Model{
    ...
    function save(){
        $result = new Result();
        // error occur
        $result.addError('bla bla1');

        // another error occur
        $result.addError('bla bla2');

        if(!$result->isSucces()){
            return $result;
        }
    }
    ....
}

class MyController extends Controller{
    ...
    function actionSave(){

        $result = $this->model->save($data2save);

        if(!$result->isSuccess()){
            // pass $result to View 

        }

    }
    ....
}
```

I added some code so it would be easier to understand.
I just think that adding the text_message to Model make it more coupling to controller and less generic.
By using error_code, one controller could interprate it differently than another controller, so the model would be much generic

Comment: At least one other popular MVC framework throws exceptions to the controller.

Comment: I already tried that, but I want to 'recover' from a single error, and instead gather all errors i find and only then send them to controller

Comment: You might find this somewhat usefull: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5864000/727208  .. also the sort answer for your question would be: neither.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are talking about validation errors. There are different approaches.

The model should validate the data and return the error messages and from the controller, depending on your framework, you can set them to the view. Very basic example:

```
$this->Model->save($data); // Should trigger Model::validate() internally.
$this->set('errors', $this->Model->validationErrors());
```

Again, depending on your framework, another, IMHO better solution would be if your model returns data *objects* and *collections* of them for multiple records. The object will contain the information about the fields it represents including it's validation errors.

I would clearly not return just an integer but whatever way you chose you should be able to map the error messages to a field so that you can displays them accordingly in your view. Again, just a basic example to make the idea clear:

```
echo $entity->errors['field_name']['validation_rule_1'];
echo $entity->errors['field_name']['validation_rule_2'];
echo $entity->errors['field_name2']['validation_rule_1'];
```

Comment: that's what I basically do(I added some code snip to my question). but i think that its better for the model to return error-codes, and the controller would parse them as suite him. that's way, other controllers could use this model and would parse the error codes as needed

Comment: So you prefer to repeat that in every controller? That's not DRY. For example usually a field that is validated to be an int will always stay an int. Also how do you deal with translations? Validation rules? Rule sets? Check any of the popular frameworks how they do it. Also I don't think it is nice to down vote every answer you don't like, especially given the fact you've asked a very vague question and provided the code later... If you don't link the answers and are already set on doing it your way, why are you asking at all?

Answer (score 1):

I'd work with error codes, so that you can handle all upcoming error codes at one, central point in your application.

Also I think that error codes are more usefull for errorhandling and errorlogging, because you can set together error codes that are similar and do different actions for them at the same code position.

But I guess that this is primary opinion based

Answer (score 0):

You should throw exceptions on errors. You can then catch the exceptions in the controller. An exception can be set with a message.

Read more about Exceptions here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: See my comment to @Chief

Comment: Depending on how he implemented the classes exceptions are not recommended to handle BBDD errors related with parameters. For instance, Code Igniter recommends not to use exceptions to handle validation/insertion errors.